# How to MySQL Condtions AND & OR

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm working on a school project, and I need this to work. I'm currently checking if my logged in users role is higher than a value, if they're great.
Instead of using precise values I'm using higher than and lower than (<=>).
I don't feel like you have to see that code.

In my MySQL Select Query I have the following:

PHP Code (Inside my $mysqli->query() which is set to a variable):

```
SELECT * FROM coachteam, teams, userteam WHERE (fk_coachteam_team_id = team_id AND fk_coachteam_user_id = '".$sessionRow['user_id']."') 
OR (fk_userteam_team_id = team_id AND fk_userteam_user_id = '".$sessionRow['user_id']."')
```

In my database I have tables called as you see above: **coachteam**, **teams**, **userteam** .
All of the fields are valid. How do I know? When I try to fetch my result I get nothing, but if I remove one of the OR conditions or I add my user to both of my many-to-many tables, results will be fetched. But not if I have my user in one of the many-to-many table.

**So example:**
If I only have my user in either **coachteam** or **userteam**, my result isn't able to fetch any arrays, if I have my user in both of these, it will be able to.
If I remove one of the OR conditions, and only have my user in one of the many-to-many, it will work with the condition specified in the MySQL.

Shouldn't it behave like, if one of the conditions is true, then use that and fetch information from that.

Help appreciated, gotta hand this in tomorrow

Comment: With what you described, I strongly suspect that you're running into an error in your condition after OR. Add this below your query to check if this is the case: `die($mysqli->error);`

Comment: I don't receive any errors. The query above is used as an variable  $result = $mysqli->query(...) or die($mysqli->error);

Comment: Try using your teams table with left joins coachteam and userteam with your fields similar like this ` SELECT * FROM teams LEFT JOIN coachteam CT ON CT.coach_team_id=T.id LEFT JOIN userteam UT ON UT.user_team_id=T.id WHERE fk_userteam_user_id=... OR fk_coachteam_user_id=...`

Comment: Never really used Left joins - I've done this: $resultUserMatchSignup = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM teams LEFT JOIN coachteam CT 
         ON CT.coach_team_id=T.id LEFT JOIN userteam UT ON UT.user_team_id=T.id WHERE fk_userteam_user_id='".$sessionRow['user_id']."' OR fk_coachteam_user_id='".$sessionRow['user_id']."'") or die($mysqli->error); 
Doesn't work.
In my own query, it works when my user is in both many-to-many tables but not if they're in one, it also works if I remove one of the statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use multiple ORs or ANDs grouped together it's good to double group them.

It's also good in MySQL when comparing data from multiple tables to include the table in the operator that you're getting the field from.

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `coachteam`,
    `teams`,
    `userteam`
  WHERE
    (
      ( `table-name`.`fk_coachteam_team_id` = `table-name`.`team_id` )
     AND
      ( `table-name`.`fk_coachteam_user_id` = '" . $sessionRow['user_id'] . "')
    ) 
    OR
    (
      ( `table-name`.`fk_userteam_team_id` = `table-name`.`team_id`)
     AND
      ( `table-name`.`fk_userteam_user_id` = '" . $sessionRow['user_id'] . "')
    )
";

$a = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($connection, $sql) );

var_dump($a);
```

Comment: $resultCoachteam = $mysqli->query("
      SELECT
       *
      FROM
       'coachteam',
       'teams',
       'userteam'
      WHERE
       (
        ( 'coachteam'.'fk_coachteam_team_id' = 'teams'.'team_id' )
        AND
          ( 'coachteam'.'fk_coachteam_user_id' = '".$sessionRow['user_id']."')
       ) 
       OR
       (
         ( 'userteam'.'fk_userteam_team_id' = 'teams'.'team_id')
        AND
         ( 'userteam'.'fk_userteam_user_id' = '".$sessionRow['user_id']."')
       )
      ") or die($mysqli->error); I now get this error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''coachteam', 'teams', 'userteam' WHERE ( ' at line 4

Comment: You appear to be using an apostrophe for defining your 'coachteam'... etc. In SQL this searches for a value, like where you originally had = '" . $ses . "', the symbol you want to be using is the `, or the grave accent.

Comment: The grave accent " ` " searches in SQL for tables, columns, or other SQL objects.

Comment: Unknown column '1' in 'where clause' I get this error, no idea what it means.

Comment: This means that you replaced every single apostrophe with a grave accent. If you do WHERE \`a\` = \`1\` it is searching for a match where column "a" equals column "1". You need to do \`a\` = '1' which will search where column "a" is equal to a value of "1". Make sure that you are still using '" . $sessionRow['user_id'] . "' (with parantheses) and not \`" . $sessionRow['user_id'] . "\` (with grave marks)

Comment: I think I'm just an idiot. It have worked all along. Just mistake on my end, anyways, thank you for your input. It didn't work because I only had one user, I now tried logging in with a new user, and it displayed even though i was only in one table.